# Magento 2.1.7 moved website redirecting to old url

Tags: php, magento2

i have installed latest magento 2.1.7 version on my server and installed a theme. I have installed magento in a folder(**http://example.com/site/**) everything is working fine there. Now i have moved it to root directory (**http://example.com/**) as a main website, but there it is not working, it redirecting to old url with SID var. **http://example.com/site/?sid=8374urh347yr7w4ry**

I have tried the following changes:

- Changed base_url in core_config_data table,
- Deleted all cache/ everything in var/
- Deleted browser cache/cookies
- I tried on localhost but yet redirecting to **http://example.com/site/?sid=8374urh347yr7w4ry**
- Deleted system tmp files
- I checked env.php file but there is nothing
- All permission set

Is magento store base_url in any file also? so that i could change.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Check data ones again by using following query. may be possible still old url records present.   select * from core_config_data where path like '%base_url%';

Comment: For me it was the web/secure/base_url - changed this then cleared the cache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As my comment solved your problem I will post it as an answer.

According to magento takes all config data from cache folder you have to clear the `magentodir/var/cache` - including all subfolders - to be sure the new config is taken.

You said you allready cleared the cache, my advice is to check this point again. (Maybe you cleared the cache before you did the necessary changes?)

Comment: As you said i tried again but same issue.... nothing happened.. actually as i enter url it redirect to  [http://example.com/site/?sid=8374urh347yr7w4ry]

Comment: Check your `.htccess` file in `magentodir` their is any redirection rule or not?

Comment: thank you! I tried to update the core_config_data table for secure and insecure path, but that doesn't do effect. But after I remove the cache, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

First thing first head over to database under table `core_config_data` chage both secure and unsecure url to your new store adress then run this

> php -dmemory_limit=2G bin/magento setup:upgrade && php
>   -dmemory_limit=2G bin/magento setup:di:compile && php -dmemory_limit=2G   bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f && php -dmemory_limit=2G bin/magento indexer:reindex && php
>   -dmemory_limit=2G bin/magento cache:flush

Answer (score 1):

For me it was setting not just base_url and secure_base_url but also **base_url_link** in in **core_config_data**.

Comment: Probably the most relevant answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart apache.

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
sudo service apache2 restart
```

For some share hosting like godaddy try to switch php version and clear browser cache.